# events removed from google calendar still appears on listEvents

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I am getting a issue when I remove a event from my application (even from google calendar too). I have my calendar with all my events, I try to remove a event for first time, and it "works": I change the tab of my browser, and see the Google Calendar panel and the event had successfully removed, great!! BUT, if I reload the tab of my application... I still see the event!!!
Also, if I remove the data from the Google Calendar Panel, the application still recover this event on the API call:

```
$service->events->listEvents($calendar,$eventsParam);
```

$service is a Google_Service_Calendar object.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

This is the way how I delete the events:

```
public function removedate()
{
    $service    = getService();
    $service->events->delete($this->input->post("calendar"), getEventId($service));
}
```

I am working with codeigniter and I am using a helper made by myself for the most habitual functions, between them these two:

```
function getService($file=false)
{
    $ci =& get_instance();
    if($file)
        $file = CREDENTIALS_PATH.$file;
    else
        $file = CREDENTIALS_PATH.$ci->session->userdata("identity").".json";
    $ci->g_client->setAccessToken(file_get_contents($file));
    return new Google_Service_Calendar($ci->g_client);
}
function getEventId($service)
{
    $ci =& get_instance();
    $id         = $ci->input->post("id");
    $dni        = $id;
    if(!is_numeric($id))
        $id     = $ci->general_model->getData("users","phone", array("dni"=>$id), true)->phone;

    $min = false;
    $max = false;
    if($ci->input->post("min"))
        $min        = date("c", strtotime ( '-2 hour' , strtotime ( (new DateTime(explode("GMT", $ci->input->post("min"))[0]))->format("c"))));
    if($ci->input->post("max"))
        $max        = (new DateTime(explode("GMT", $ci->input->post("max"))[0]))->format("c");
    $events     = getDates($service, $ci->input->post("calendar"), $min, $max);
    foreach ($events->getItems() as $event)
    {
        if($id==$event->getSummary() || $dni==$event->getSummary())
            return $event->getId();
    }
}
```

**NEW EDIT**

One more thing... when I remove a event for first time there is no problem (and the event is DELETED on the google calendar), and when I refresh my app page the event still remains, and when I try to delete it again I get this error:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling DELETE 
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/cnhkehagcve7rm8s1g88hauer8%40group.calendar.google.com/events/97smpf2320s3lmg8nnnpb9dndc: (410) 
Resource has been deleted' in
/var/www/html/prototipo/application/third_party/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php:110
```

RESOURCE HAS BEEN DELETED... Yes!!! I know!!! why does it remain??????

Comment: Please cross check your event id and calendar_id are correct ...

Comment: Hi @Vipin. Yes... I watched the calendar id and it match withmy google calendar Id, about the event id, how can I see the id on google calendar panel??

Comment: $events = $service->events->listEvents($calendarListEntry->id); var_dump($events); try this , you will get event id  thn run below code$result = $service->events->delete('calendar_id', 'event_id');
echo "<br>========================<br>";
var_dump($result);
echo "<br>========================<br>";

Comment: please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app should not display events with status=cancelled.

Comment: Thanks @luc ... this was the problem. I don´t know why on the code I wrote $eventsParameters["showDeleted"] = true; :/ Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To get **all** events

```
$events = $service->events->listEvents('<calendar_id>');
```

To **remove** any event from calendar

```
    $result = $service->events->delete('<calendar_id>', '<event_id>');
    echo "<br>========================<br>";
    var_dump($result);
    echo "<br>========================<br>";
```

Comment: Yes it is how I do... I am going to edit my question to give more info about how I do that.

Comment: Hi @Vipin... is there anyway to know the id of a event on the google calendar panel?? I can know the id of the events after make $events = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $eventsParam); var_dump($events);

Comment: @EloyFernándezFranco , I do n't know how to get event id on calendar panel, why you need event id on panel ?

Comment: Only for compare if the id on the panel is the same than the id returned by the API... the id of the calendar are the same on the panel than on the app, so I guest the id of event must be the same, but....

Comment: You can get correct event id from script if you know what is name of event.... or time .... which is unique and thn we can do what ever you want....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111494/discussion-between-vipin-sharma-and-eloy-fernandez-franco).